# f2py won't compile with negative indexes for vector parameter

Tags: f2py

Say I have a module to be compiled via `f2py`:

> test.f90

```
module test
implicit none

integer, parameter :: q = 2
real(8), parameter, dimension(-q:q) :: vec = (/ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 /)

contains

subroutine writevec()
    write(*,*) vec
end subroutine

end module
```

Upon running `f2py -c -m test test.f90`, I get the error

```
/tmp/tmp6X6gsD/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/testmodule.c:176:17: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
{"vec",1,{{-(-)+1}},NPY_DOUBLE},
```

On the other hand, if I declare `vec` with `dimension(2*q+1)`, it works. Sort of. When I import into python:

```
>>> from test import test
>>> test.writevec()
>>>    1.0000000000000000        2.0000000000000000        3.0000000000000000        4.0000000000000000        5.0000000000000000     

>>> test.vec
>>> array([ 1.,  2.]) # ???
```

What is going on here??

Answer (score 0):

You can create a signature file in order to get the array dimensions right. This creates the signature file 'sign.pyf' for the python module 'mymod':

```
f2py -m mymod -h sign.pyf test.f90
```

Then, use this to compile:

```
f2py -c sign.pyf test.f90
```

The library can be imported and used in Python as:

```
>>>import mymod
>>>mymod.test.writevec()
```

Note, that the array bounds are shifted and the first element has the index 0 in Python:

```
>>>import mymod
>>>mymod.test.vec #output: array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.])
>>>mymod.test.vec[0] #output: 1.0
```